# "push_patch" won't update URL

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, phoenix-live-view

I have a component for pagination. It works but there's one issue: it won't replace or update the URL in the browser dynamically. Namely, when I change a page -- 2nd, 3rd, 4th page of the data in a table -- I want **the URL** to get updated as well: updated in the browser URL bar and appended to the browser history.

```
my_domain.com/my/pigs?page=2&page_size=5
my_domain.com/my/pigs?page=3&page_size=5
my_domain.com/my/pigs?page=66&page_size=5
```

But at the moment only data will get fetched correctly, according to the current page, whereas the URL will remain always static - `my_domain.com/my/pigs`

```
  @impl true
  def handle_info({:update, opts}, socket) do
    extra_params = merge_and_sanitize_params(socket, opts)
    path = "/my/pigs"
    to = path <> "?" <> URI.encode_query(extra_params)

    # socket = push_patch(socket, to: to, replace: true)
    socket = push_patch(socket, to: to)

    {:noreply, socket}
  end
```

I've tried `replace` with `true`, and without -- the URL will stay "my/pigs" no matter what.

The `_url` in `handle_params(..)`  will contain the correct one -- with `?page=X&page_size=Y` which is correct:

```
  @impl true
  def handle_params(params, _url, socket) do
    # _url will contain dynamic url, with the correct params
    # .....
```

However, the the URL in browser the will still remain static.

What's the matter?

---

Here's a part of my pagination component

```
      <div class="page-stepper">
        <%= for {page_number, current_page?} <- pages(@pagination) do %>
          <div phx-click="show_page"
            phx-value-page={page_number}
            phx-target={@myself}
            class={if current_page?, do: "active"}
          ><%= page_number %></div>
        <% end %>
      </div>
```

And

```
  # ...........
  def handle_event("show_page", params, socket) do
    # ..........
    # opts ---> page, page_size
    # 
    send(self(), {:update, opts})
    {:noreply, socket}
    # ........
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix_html/issues/417

According to this GitHub issue it might be your `phoenix_html` version.
You should probably downgrade `phoenix_html` to 3.2 or upgrade `phoenix_live_view` to latest version.

We just ran into the same issue recently.